# jQuery syntax for if checking if class along with keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, syntax, keycode

I am writing an interaction and need a bit of syntax help on one element:

Need to check "IF" a class is present on a div

```
<div class="something">
```

and the "Enter" key is pressed (key 13)

```
switch (window.event.keyCode) {
        case 13:
        window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
        break;
}
```

then run a function

```
$('#thing').addClass('that');
```

What would proper jQuery or JS Syntax be for something like this?

So to clear things up: I have a div with classes that are changing. I am trying to get the browser to detect when said class is present on the dive "AND" the enter button is pressed, then run a function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dshell/q4qwH/)

You can check for the class within your keypress function:

```
$(function() {

    $(window).keypress(function(event) 
    { 
        if ((event.keyCode == 13) && ($('div').hasClass('this')))
        { 
            $('#thing').addClass('that');
        } 
    });

});
```

You may want to change the generic `div` to check whether a *certain* div has the class by its `id`

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks Danny. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey Danny, is there a "best practice" method of running functions on keypress order?  Like if in your example above, the user pressed key 13 and it ran the first function. How could I run a different function if the user pressed the same key again?

Comment: Here is a fiddle that is tracking how many times the user has hit Enter (and the div has the class): http://jsfiddle.net/dshell/qjLZm/. You may want to be doing something completely different, rather than just adding a different class, but then you could just make a different function call in `case 2` rather than calling `addClass`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#thing').hasClass('that')) { // your code };
```

Simple as that. Check out the jQuery docs some time. Usually if you need to do anything, there's a function for it already.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Would I just place the keycode case within the // your code area?

Comment: Here's what I would do.
    $(window).on('keyDown', function(e){ 
        if(e.keyCode == 13 && $('#thing').hasClass('that')){
            window.location.href = "www.google.com";
        }  
    })

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the jquery function .hasClass()

https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

like

```
if($("#thing").hasClass("something")){
    $("#thing").addClass("that");
}
```

I don't completely understand understand what you are trying to do to incorporate it in your code.

Comment: Thanks! I added a bit of text up top to add more clarity. Thank you for your help!